Calc's implicit multiplication in Latex
I am having a problem concerning emacs "Calc" calculator.
I am trying to implement a function to write math equations in latex from an input written in calc (algebraic notation). So I use calc with latex language mode and with no-simplify-mode.
I have come up with the function below.
(defun calc-to-math-latex (calc-string)
    "Interactive function to insert some math latex formulas from calc"
    (interactive "sAlgebraic expression: ")
    (insert (calc-eval '("$" calc-language latex calc-simplify-mode none) nil calc-string)))

But when I try to write "3*5" for instance it will insert "3 5" (an implicit multiplication) and I would like something like "3\cdot 5".
How can we change this behaviour ?
I have searched "The GNU Emacs Calculator" manual for some answers... but I am not sure where to look for. I think it might have something to do with "Syntax Tables" https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/calc.html#Syntax-Tables
